# How to get value by dynamic field Name using sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am passing dynamic column name base that column name  to get the value and below i my table

```
Table_CandidateInfo

Id     Name        Age    City 

1      Mazhar      30     Gulbarga

20     Khan        29     Bidar
```

Example1

```
Declare @ColumnName varchar(100), @Id int

set @ColumnName='Age' 
set @Id=20

select * from Table_CandidateInfo where ID=@Id and
```

I am not able to pass ColumnName with `and` query because column name is dynamic pass by code. My output should be

```
29
```

Example2: If my @ColumnName='City'  and @Id=20 then output should be like below

```
Bidar
```

Comment: If you have the time, read [this article on dynamic SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and [this one on dynamic search conditions](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), if that's what you're using this for. Dynamic SQL is a big topic, but that's because people often use it unnecessarily, incorrectly or in ways that are difficult to get to perform right. A simple "here's how you do it" answer will skip all over that.

Comment: I will read if you answer then it will help to me understand more. @JeroenMostert

Comment: Why force Jeroen to answer @mohdmazharkhan? Those links are useful and informative, and you shouldn't ignore them just because they're in the comments. The comments are actually the correct place for link only answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are actually after is the below:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname, @Id int;
SET @Id = 29;
SET @ColumnName = N'Age';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' FROM dbo.Table_CandidateInfo WHERE Id = @Id;';
--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Id int', @Id = @Id;
```

Comment: why you attached N with ColumnName  like N'Age';. @Larnu

Comment: Because the string literal is an `nvarchar`. For example object names use the data type `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`. It's normally a good idea to pass an `nvarchar` to an `nvarchar`, so I ensure I declare my literal strings as one. This also means that if you do end up with a non-ASCII character in your code, it isn't implicitly changed to `'?'`.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, you cannot pass identifiers as parameters.  You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @columnName varchar(100);
declare @Id int;

set @ColumnName = 'Age' ;
set @Id = 20;

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select *
from Table_CandidateInfo
where [columnName] = @Id';

select @sql = replace(@sql, '[columnName]', quotename(@columnName));

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@id int',
                   @id=@id;
```

Comment: I suggest properly quoting the dynamic column name here, otherwise this is just a injection issue waiting to happen.

Comment: i am not understanding where i can get single value output like 29. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Larnu . . . Did you downvote the answer because of that?

Comment: still error is showing: Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query. @GordonLinoff

Comment: A few minutes ago. Injection is still far too a large problem in the industry and needs to be addressed. As the answer in my view is dangerous, I did add a downvote after awhile. Of course, now that it's resolved I've changed it to an upvote.

Comment: You should have been able to work that one yourself mohdmazharkhan, there was an alias before the `*` but the object didn't have one. As there's only one object I removed the alias for you here

Comment: I got my answer from above answer thanks your effort for me, but your answer not help full to me. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Larnu . . . A comment would have been sufficient.  Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I did comment though Gordon, and maybe 30 minutes later the Injection was still there. It was the downvote that got your attention in the end, not the comment; which seems to show that the downvote did its job. I will normally just comment, but if that's ignored then a downvote for dangerous code is warrented for what is dangerous code (in my view). But like I did if that's addressed in always more than happy to change the vote (it is up to the voter how they use their votes after all). :)