# How to Update value by dynamic field Name using sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am passing dynamic column name base that column name  to Update the value and below i my table

```
Table_CandidateInfo

Id     Name        Age    City 

1      Mazhar      30     Gulbarga

20     Khan        29     Bidar
```

Example1

```
Declare @ColumnName varchar(100), @Id int

set @ColumnName='City' 
set @Id=20
set @value='Hyderabad'

update set ____ Table_CandidateInfo where ID=@Id
```

my output should like below Table_CandidateInfo, Hyderabad City updated base on Id and Column name

```
Table_CandidateInfo

Id     Name        Age    City 

1      Mazhar      30     Gulbarga

20     Khan        29     Hyderabad
```

Column name is dynamic some time @ColumnName='Name' so name value should update

Yesterday i have asked for get data base on column value that working fine but now i need to update

[How to get value by dynamic field Name using sql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324589/how-to-get-value-by-dynamic-field-name-using-sql-select-query/56324796#56324796)

Comment: Read about dynamic SQL in SQL Server: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: let it be can you answer. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you can't parameterize identifiers in SQL, your only option would be to use dynamic SQL for such things.
However, please note that the code that creates and execute the dynamic SQL statement needs to be written in such a way it would prevent SQL injection attacks.
The rule is quite simple - what you can't parameterize must be white-listed.

So basically, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCandidateInfo
(
     @ColumnName sysname, 
     @Id int,
     @value sql_Variant
)

AS

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE Table_Name = 'Table_CandidateInfo'
    AND Column_Name = @ColumnName
)

BEGIN

    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = N'Update Table_CandidateInfo SET '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N' = @Value WHERE Id = @Id';

    DECLARE @Params nvarchar(4000) = N'@Value sql_Variant, @Id int'

    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @Sql, @Params, @Value, @Id
END

GO
```

Please note that the code was written directly here and therefor untested - there might be mistakes in it but that's the general idea.

[`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) is a system data type which is used by SQL server for all identifiers. It's basically an alias to `nvarchar(128)`, except it's non-nullable.

[`sql_variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a special data type which can be used to hold different data types inside.

use [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to enable the use of column names containing spaces, dots, or that are reserved keywords.

Comment: Glad to help :-)